# Load AJAX content from a link on a different page

Tags: javascript, ajax

I would like to create a link, let's call it "Monday's Schedule". When you click on that link, it loads the "Schedule" page and the "ajaxoutput" div is pre-populated with "view_games_monday.php" as shown in the function below.

Currently, the link pertaining to the function below is on the page "Schedule" which is the SAME page that has the "ajaxoutput" div.

```
document.getElementById('games_monday').onclick = function()
{
    callPage('view_games_monday.php',document.getElementById("ajaxoutput"));
}


<a href="#" id="games_monday">monday</a>

<div id="ajaxoutput">
</div>
```

So how can I setup the "Monday's Schedule" link to load the "Schedule" page with the "view_games_monday.php" pre-populated in the "ajaxoutput" div? My issue is that "Monday's Schedule" link is not on the "Schedule" page.

Sorry for all the quotes just trying to be clear.

Thank you for your help.

I've tried the following and can get the Schedule page to load but not with the correct ajax output:

```
document.getElementById('schedule_monday').onclick = function()
    {
        location = "http://mydomain.com/schedule";
        this.document.location.href = location;
        window.onload = callPage('http://mydomain.com/view_games_monday.php',document.getElementById("ajaxoutput"));
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why everything is on different pages, and I'm not fully clear on which part isn't working. If one page needs to conditionally load content, you typically make an ajax call to the server, determine which content needs to load, and then return it. you can use the response html to populate the div. But do remember, ajax won't work cross-domain, just in case you were trying that.

Comment: So I have a single Schedule page that displays games and on that page there are links for each day of the week (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, etc.) and those links allow you to filter the games by the day.

In the main navigation menu (that appears on all pages of the site) there are also links "Monday's Schedule" "Tuesday's Schedule" etc. so if you're on a page other than Schedule, when you click on one of the main navigation menu links above, I am trying to get it to load the Schedule page with the corresponding games for that day already loaded by default.

Comment: I'd suggest not using multiple pages. If you're using javascript anyway, you can print all the information to a single page, hide the content you don't need yet, and then use javascript to toggle different divs when needed. It saves the user waiting for additional http requests. Look at any javascript-based tab or slider content systems for an example if you need.

Comment: I commented before your edit. In that case, have the other links pass a value to the schedule page, like /schedule?day=monday

Comment: I appreciate your response. I've passed those values with each link, but not sure where to go next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on our comment discussion, here's what I suggest based on my understanding of what you want.

You only need a single page, `index.php`. This is extremely basic, but conveys the point:

```
<?php

$scheduleDay = (isset($_GET['day']) ? $_GET['day'] : 'monday');

if( $scheduleDay == "monday" ){
   print 'stuff for monday goes here';
}
else if( $scheduleDay == "tuesday" ){
   print 'stuff for tuesday goes here';
}
```

Then, in your navigation menu, just use: `index.php?day=tuesday`, etc.

When the php file detects the day, it will print the corresponding information. No javascript even needed.

You could make it fancier like I had mentioned, and print all of the schedules onto a page and use javascript to display only a single day, but I assume this example is what you're looking for.

Comment: Sure, I understand that approach via PHP. I was originally planning to use both and keep the AJAX, but I think I'm going to throw out that idea now and just go with the PHP. Thanks for your help.

Comment: From what you've described I think ajax isn't needed. PHP is effective with showing content conditionally but even if you want to avoid the page-refresh when someone clicks a link, it'd be easier to use javascript to show content already hidden on the page. AJAX requires an http request and some sort of listener on the server to respond - and that's extra work that you don't need here. The conditional javascript using hidden elements would be extremely fast - best user experience.